# Restoring iomanip in Visual Studio after getting C2059 error

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Currently learning C++ using Visual Studio and I've a simple code that won't compile but runs fine with g++ in Linux. I noticed there's an error code of C2059 in `iomanip` and saw this line:

```
_NODISCARD _MRTIMP2 _Smanip<streamsize> __cdecl (streamsize); // This should be setprecision(streamsize) I believe(?)
_NODISCARD _MRTIMP2 _Smanip<streamsize> __cdecl setw(streamsize);
```

Which suggests that I may have accidentally edited it. Is there a way to restore iomanip (or any other external dependency that one might accidentally alter for that matter) to default in VS? I've tried creating a new project to no avail.

Comment: Hi @drescherjm, I've always been able to edit the shipped files. What I'll do is open the headers folder and set all the files to read only. Just checked, and I need to do that!

Comment: You are correct about the accidental editing. I thought because it was in C:\Program Files that it would not be writable without UAC stepping in.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you could change `__cdecl (streamsize);` to `__cdecl setprecision(streamsize);`.

If it doesn't work, I suggest that you could reinstall VS.

Here is the `iomaip.h`:

```
// iomanip standard header
#pragma once
#ifndef _IOMANIP_
#define _IOMANIP_
#ifndef RC_INVOKED
#include <istream>

#include <type_traits>

#include <xlocmon>
#include <xloctime>

 #pragma pack(push,_CRT_PACKING)
 #pragma warning(push,3)
 #pragma push_macro("new")
 #undef new

_STD_BEGIN
        // TEMPLATE STRUCT _Fillobj
template<class _Elem>
    struct _Fillobj
    {   // store fill character
    _Fillobj(_Elem _Ch)
        : _Fill(_Ch)
        {   // construct from fill character
        }

    _Elem _Fill;    // the fill character
    };

        // TEMPLATE FUNCTION setfill
template<class _Elem> inline
    _Fillobj<_Elem> setfill(_Elem _Ch)
    {   // return a _Fillobj manipulator
    return (_Fillobj<_Elem>(_Ch));
    }

template<class _Elem,
    class _Traits,
    class _Elem2> inline
    basic_istream<_Elem, _Traits>&
        operator>>(basic_istream<_Elem, _Traits>& _Istr,
            const _Fillobj<_Elem2>& _Manip)
    {   // set fill character in input stream
    static_assert(is_same<_Elem, _Elem2>::value,
        "wrong character type for setfill");

    _Istr.fill(_Manip._Fill);
    return (_Istr);
    }

template<class _Elem,
    class _Traits,
    class _Elem2> inline
    basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>&
        operator<<(basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>& _Ostr,
            const _Fillobj<_Elem2>& _Manip)
    {   // set fill character in output stream
    static_assert(is_same<_Elem, _Elem2>::value,
        "wrong character type for setfill");

    _Ostr.fill(_Manip._Fill);
    return (_Ostr);
    }

        // TEMPLATE STRUCT _Monobj
template<class _Money>
    struct _Monobj
    {   // store reference to monetary amount
    _Monobj(_Money& _Val_arg, bool _Intl_arg)
        : _Val(_Val_arg), _Intl(_Intl_arg)
        {   // construct from monetary amount reference and int'l flag
        }

    _Money& _Val;   // the monetary amount reference
    bool _Intl;     // international flag

    private:
        _Monobj& operator=(const _Monobj&);
    };

        // TEMPLATE FUNCTION get_money
template<class _Money> inline
    _Monobj<_Money> get_money(_Money& _Val_arg,
        bool _Intl_arg = false)
    {   // return a _Monobj manipulator
    return (_Monobj<_Money>(_Val_arg, _Intl_arg));
    }

template<class _Elem,
    class _Traits,
    class _Money> inline
    basic_istream<_Elem, _Traits>&
        operator>>(basic_istream<_Elem, _Traits>& _Istr,
            const _Monobj<_Money>& _Manip)
    {   // get monetary amount from input stream
    typedef basic_istream<_Elem, _Traits> _Myis;
    typedef istreambuf_iterator<_Elem, _Traits> _Iter;
    typedef money_get<_Elem, _Iter> _Mymget;

    ios_base::iostate _State = ios_base::goodbit;
    const typename _Myis::sentry _Ok(_Istr);

    if (_Ok)
        {   // state okay, extract monetary amount
        const _Mymget& _Mget_fac = _USE(_Istr.getloc(), _Mymget);
        _TRY_IO_BEGIN
        _Mget_fac.get(_Iter(_Istr.rdbuf()), _Iter(0), _Manip._Intl,
            _Istr, _State, _Manip._Val);
        _CATCH_IO_(_Istr)
        }

    _Istr.setstate(_State);
    return (_Istr);
    }

        // TEMPLATE FUNCTION put_money
template<class _Money> inline
    _Monobj<const _Money>
        put_money(const _Money& _Val_arg,
            bool _Intl_arg = false)
    {   // return a _Monobj manipulator
    return (_Monobj<const _Money>(_Val_arg, _Intl_arg));
    }

template<class _Elem,
    class _Traits,
    class _Money> inline
    basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>&
        operator<<(basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>& _Ostr,
            const _Monobj<_Money>& _Manip)
    {   // put monetary amount to output stream
    typedef basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits> _Myos;
    typedef ostreambuf_iterator<_Elem, _Traits> _Iter;
    typedef money_put<_Elem, _Iter> _Mymput;

    ios_base::iostate _State = ios_base::goodbit;
    const typename _Myos::sentry _Ok(_Ostr);

    if (_Ok)
        {   // state okay, insert monetary amount
        const _Mymput& _Mput_fac = _USE(_Ostr.getloc(), _Mymput);
        _TRY_IO_BEGIN
        if (_Mput_fac.put(_Iter(_Ostr.rdbuf()), _Manip._Intl,
            _Ostr, _Ostr.fill(), _Manip._Val).failed())
                _State |= ios_base::badbit;
        _CATCH_IO_(_Ostr)
        }

    _Ostr.setstate(_State);
    return (_Ostr);
    }

        // TEMPLATE STRUCT _Timeobj
template<class _Elem,
    class _Ptr>
    struct _Timeobj
    {   // store reference to tm object and format
    _Timeobj(_Ptr _Tptr_arg, const _Elem *_Fmt_arg)
        : _Tptr(_Tptr_arg), _Fmtfirst(_Fmt_arg)
        {   // construct from tm pointer and format pointer
        for (_Fmtlast = _Fmtfirst; *_Fmtlast != 0; ++_Fmtlast)
            ;   // find end of format string
        }

    _Ptr _Tptr; // the tm struct pointer
    const _Elem *_Fmtfirst; // format string start
    const _Elem *_Fmtlast;  // format string end
    };

        // TEMPLATE FUNCTION get_time
template<class _Elem> inline
    _Timeobj<_Elem, struct tm *>
        get_time(struct tm *_Tptr_arg, const _Elem *_Fmt_arg)
    {   // return a _Timeobj manipulator
    return (_Timeobj<_Elem, struct tm *>(_Tptr_arg, _Fmt_arg));
    }

template<class _Elem,
    class _Traits,
    class _Elem2> inline
    basic_istream<_Elem, _Traits>&
        operator>>(basic_istream<_Elem, _Traits>& _Istr,
            const _Timeobj<_Elem2, struct tm *>& _Manip)
    {   // get time information from input stream
    typedef basic_istream<_Elem, _Traits> _Myis;
    typedef istreambuf_iterator<_Elem, _Traits> _Iter;
    typedef time_get<_Elem2, _Iter> _Mytget;

    static_assert(is_same<_Elem, _Elem2>::value,
        "wrong character type for get_time");

    ios_base::iostate _State = ios_base::goodbit;
    const typename _Myis::sentry _Ok(_Istr);

    if (_Ok)
        {   // state okay, extract time amounts
        const _Mytget& _Tget_fac = _USE(_Istr.getloc(), _Mytget);
        _TRY_IO_BEGIN
        _Tget_fac.get(_Iter(_Istr.rdbuf()), _Iter(0), _Istr, _State,
            _Manip._Tptr, _Manip._Fmtfirst, _Manip._Fmtlast);
        _CATCH_IO_(_Istr)
        }

    _Istr.setstate(_State);
    return (_Istr);
    }

        // TEMPLATE FUNCTION put_time
template<class _Elem> inline
    _Timeobj<_Elem, const struct tm *>
        put_time(const struct tm *_Tptr_arg, const _Elem *_Fmt_arg)
    {   // return a _Timeobj manipulator
    return (_Timeobj<_Elem, const struct tm *>(_Tptr_arg, _Fmt_arg));
    }

template<class _Elem,
    class _Traits,
    class _Elem2> inline
    basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>&
        operator<<(basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>& _Ostr,
            const _Timeobj<_Elem2, const struct tm *>& _Manip)
    {   // put time information to output stream
    typedef basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits> _Myos;
    typedef ostreambuf_iterator<_Elem, _Traits> _Iter;
    typedef time_put<_Elem2, _Iter> _Mytput;

    static_assert(is_same<_Elem, _Elem2>::value,
        "wrong character type for put_time");

    ios_base::iostate _State = ios_base::goodbit;
    const typename _Myos::sentry _Ok(_Ostr);

    if (_Ok)
        {   // state okay, insert monetary amount
        const _Mytput& _Tput_fac = _USE(_Ostr.getloc(), _Mytput);
        _TRY_IO_BEGIN
        if (_Tput_fac.put(_Iter(_Ostr.rdbuf()), _Ostr, _Ostr.fill(),
            _Manip._Tptr, _Manip._Fmtfirst, _Manip._Fmtlast).failed())
            _State |= ios_base::badbit;
        _CATCH_IO_(_Ostr)
        }

    _Ostr.setstate(_State);
    return (_Ostr);
    }
        // TEMPLATE STRUCT _Quote_in
template<class _Elem,
    class _Traits,
    class _Alloc>
    struct _Quote_in
    {   // store reference to string
    typedef basic_string<_Elem, _Traits, _Alloc> _Mystr;

    _Quote_in(_Mystr& _Str_obj,
        _Elem _Delim_obj, _Elem _Escape_obj)
        : _Str(_Str_obj),
            _Delim(_Delim_obj), _Escape(_Escape_obj)
        {   // construct from string, delimiter, and escape
        }

    _Mystr& _Str;   // reference to string
    _Elem _Delim;   // delimiter element
    _Elem _Escape;  // escape element

    _Quote_in& operator=(const _Quote_in&) = delete;
    };

        // TEMPLATE STRUCT _Quote_out
template<class _Elem,
    class _Traits,
    class _Sizet>
    struct _Quote_out
    {   // store pointer/length for string
    _Quote_out(const _Elem *_Ptr_obj, _Sizet _Size_obj,
        _Elem _Delim_obj, _Elem _Escape_obj)
        : _Ptr(_Ptr_obj), _Size(_Size_obj),
            _Delim(_Delim_obj), _Escape(_Escape_obj)
        {   // construct from string, delimiter, and escape
        }

    const _Elem *_Ptr;  // pointer to string
    _Sizet _Size;   // length of string
    _Elem _Delim;   // delimiter element
    _Elem _Escape;  // escape element

    _Quote_out& operator=(const _Quote_out&) = delete;
    };

        // TEMPLATE FUNCTION quoted
template<class _Elem> inline
    _Quote_out<_Elem, void, size_t>
        quoted(const _Elem *_Ptr,
            _Elem _Delim = _Elem('"'),
            _Elem _Escape = _Elem('\\'))
    {   // return a _Quote_out manipulator for pointer/length
    size_t _Size = 0;
    for (; _Ptr[_Size] != _Elem(0); ++_Size)
        ;
    return (_Quote_out<_Elem, void, size_t>(_Ptr, _Size, _Delim, _Escape));
    }

template<class _Elem,
    class _Traits,
    class _Alloc> inline
    _Quote_out<_Elem, _Traits,
        typename basic_string<_Elem, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type>
        quoted(const basic_string<_Elem, _Traits, _Alloc>& _Str,
            _Elem _Delim = _Elem('"'),
            _Elem _Escape = _Elem('\\'))
    {   // return a _Quote_out manipulator for string
    typedef _Quote_out<_Elem, _Traits,
        typename basic_string<_Elem, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type> _Qobj;
    return (_Qobj(_Str.c_str(), _Str.size(), _Delim, _Escape));
    }

template<class _Elem,
    class _Traits,
    class _Alloc> inline
    _Quote_in<_Elem, _Traits, _Alloc>
        quoted(basic_string<_Elem, _Traits, _Alloc>& _Str,
            _Elem _Delim = _Elem('"'),
            _Elem _Escape = _Elem('\\'))
    {   // return a _Quote_in manipulator
    return (_Quote_in<_Elem, _Traits, _Alloc>(_Str, _Delim, _Escape));
    }

    // quoted INSERTER
template<class _Elem,
    class _Traits,
    class _QuTraits,
    class _Sizet> inline
    basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>&
        operator<<(basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>& _Ostr,
            const _Quote_out<_Elem, _QuTraits, _Sizet>& _Manip)
    {   // put quoted string to output stream
    static_assert(is_void<_QuTraits>::value
        || is_same<_QuTraits, _Traits>::value,
        "quoted() traits must match basic_ostream traits");

    typedef basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits> _Myos;

    const _Elem *const _Last = _Manip._Ptr + _Manip._Size;

    _Sizet _Size = _Manip._Size + 2;    // allow for delimiters
    for (const _Elem *_Ptr = _Manip._Ptr; _Ptr != _Last; ++_Ptr)
        if (_Traits::eq(*_Ptr, _Manip._Delim)
            || _Traits::eq(*_Ptr, _Manip._Escape))
            ++_Size;    // count escapes

    ios_base::iostate _State = ios_base::goodbit;
    _Sizet _Pad = _Ostr.width() <= 0 || (_Sizet)_Ostr.width() <= _Size
        ? 0 : (_Sizet)_Ostr.width() - _Size;
    const typename _Myos::sentry _Ok(_Ostr);

    if (!_Ok)
        _State |= ios_base::badbit;
    else
        {   // state okay, insert characters
    _TRY_IO_BEGIN
        if ((_Ostr.flags() & ios_base::adjustfield) != ios_base::left)
            for (; 0 < _Pad; --_Pad)    // pad on left
                if (_Traits::eq_int_type(_Traits::eof(),
                    _Ostr.rdbuf()->sputc(_Ostr.fill())))
                    {   // insertion failed, quit
                    _State |= ios_base::badbit;
                    break;
                    }

        if (_State == ios_base::goodbit
            && _Traits::eq_int_type(_Traits::eof(),
                _Ostr.rdbuf()->sputc(_Manip._Delim)))   // put delimiter
            _State |= ios_base::badbit;

        for (const _Elem *_Ptr = _Manip._Ptr; _Ptr != _Last; ++_Ptr)
            {   // put (possibly escaped) element
            if ((_Traits::eq(*_Ptr, _Manip._Delim)
                || _Traits::eq(*_Ptr, _Manip._Escape))
                && _State == ios_base::goodbit
                && _Traits::eq_int_type(_Traits::eof(),
                    _Ostr.rdbuf()->sputc(_Manip._Escape)))  // put escape
                {   // insertion failed, quit
                _State |= ios_base::badbit;
                break;
                }
            if (_State == ios_base::goodbit
                && _Traits::eq_int_type(_Traits::eof(),
                    _Ostr.rdbuf()->sputc(*_Ptr)))   // put element
                {   // insertion failed, quit
                _State |= ios_base::badbit;
                break;
                }
            }
        if (_State == ios_base::goodbit
            && _Traits::eq_int_type(_Traits::eof(),
                _Ostr.rdbuf()->sputc(_Manip._Delim)))   // put delimiter
            _State |= ios_base::badbit;

        if (_State == ios_base::goodbit)
            for (; 0 < _Pad; --_Pad)    // pad on right
                if (_Traits::eq_int_type(_Traits::eof(),
                    _Ostr.rdbuf()->sputc(_Ostr.fill())))
                    {   // insertion failed, quit
                    _State |= ios_base::badbit;
                    break;
                    }
        _Ostr.width(0);
        _CATCH_IO_(_Ostr)
        }

    _Ostr.setstate(_State);
    return (_Ostr);
    }

template<class _Elem,
    class _Traits,
    class _Alloc> inline
    basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>&
        operator<<(basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>& _Ostr,
        const _Quote_in<_Elem, _Traits, _Alloc>& _Manip)
    {   // put quoted string to output stream
    typedef basic_string<_Elem, _Traits, _Alloc> _Mystr;
    const _Mystr& _Ref = _Manip._Str;
    return (_Ostr << _STD quoted(_Ref, _Manip._Delim, _Manip._Escape));
    }

    // quoted EXTRACTOR
template<class _Elem,
    class _Traits,
    class _Alloc> inline
    basic_istream<_Elem, _Traits>& operator>>(
        basic_istream<_Elem, _Traits>& _Istr,
        const _Quote_in<_Elem, _Traits, _Alloc>& _Manip)
    {   // get quoted string from input stream
    typedef basic_istream<_Elem, _Traits> _Myis;
    typedef basic_string<_Elem, _Traits, _Alloc> _Mystr;
    typedef typename _Mystr::size_type _Sizet;

    ios_base::iostate _State = ios_base::goodbit;
    bool _Changed = false;
    const typename _Myis::sentry _Ok(_Istr);

    while (_Ok)
        {   // state okay, extract characters
        _TRY_IO_BEGIN
        _Sizet _Size = 0 < _Istr.width()
            && (_Sizet)_Istr.width() < _Manip._Str.max_size()
                ? (_Sizet)_Istr.width() : _Manip._Str.max_size();
        typename _Traits::int_type _Meta = _Istr.rdbuf()->sgetc();
        typename _Traits::int_type _Delim =
            _Traits::to_int_type(_Manip._Delim);
        typename _Traits::int_type _Escape =
            _Traits::to_int_type(_Manip._Escape);

        if (!_Traits::eq_int_type(_Meta, _Delim))   // no leading delimiter
            return (_Istr >> _Manip._Str);
        _Manip._Str.clear();
        _Meta = _Istr.rdbuf()->snextc();    // discard leading delimiter

        for (; !_Traits::eq_int_type(_Meta, _Delim) && 0 < _Size;
            _Meta = _Istr.rdbuf()->snextc(), --_Size)
            if (_Traits::eq_int_type(_Traits::eof(), _Meta))
                {   // end of file, quit
                _State |= ios_base::eofbit;
                break;
                }
            else if (!_Traits::eq_int_type(_Meta, _Escape))
                _Manip._Str.append(1,
                    _Traits::to_char_type(_Meta));  // add element
            else if (_Traits::eq_int_type(_Traits::eof(),
                _Meta = _Istr.rdbuf()->snextc()))
                {   // escaped end of file, quit
                _State |= ios_base::eofbit;
                break;
                }
            else
                _Manip._Str.append(1,
                    _Traits::to_char_type(_Meta));  // add escaped element

        if (!_Traits::eq_int_type(_Meta, _Delim))
            _State |= ios_base::failbit;    // no trailing delimiter, fail
        else
            {   // discard trailing delimiter
            _Changed = true;
            _Istr.rdbuf()->snextc();
            }
        _CATCH_IO_(_Istr)
        break;
        }

    _Istr.width(0);
    if (!_Changed)
        _State |= ios_base::failbit;
    _Istr.setstate(_State);
    return (_Istr);
    }

        // TEMPLATE STRUCT _Smanip
template<class _Arg>
    struct _Smanip
    {   // store function pointer and argument value
    _Smanip(void (__cdecl *_Left)(ios_base&, _Arg), _Arg _Val)
        : _Pfun(_Left), _Manarg(_Val)
        {   // construct from function pointer and argument value
        }

    void (__cdecl *_Pfun)(ios_base&, _Arg); // the function pointer
    _Arg _Manarg;   // the argument value
    };

template<class _Elem,
    class _Traits,
    class _Arg> inline
    basic_istream<_Elem, _Traits>& operator>>(
        basic_istream<_Elem, _Traits>& _Istr, const _Smanip<_Arg>& _Manip)
    {   // extract by calling function with input stream and argument
    (*_Manip._Pfun)(_Istr, _Manip._Manarg);
    return (_Istr);
    }

template<class _Elem,
    class _Traits,
    class _Arg> inline
    basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>& operator<<(
        basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>& _Ostr, const _Smanip<_Arg>& _Manip)
    {   // insert by calling function with output stream and argument
    (*_Manip._Pfun)(_Ostr, _Manip._Manarg);
    return (_Ostr);
    }

        // INSTANTIATIONS
_MRTIMP2 _Smanip<ios_base::fmtflags> __cdecl resetiosflags(ios_base::fmtflags);
_MRTIMP2 _Smanip<ios_base::fmtflags> __cdecl setiosflags(ios_base::fmtflags);
_MRTIMP2 _Smanip<int> __cdecl setbase(int);
_MRTIMP2 _Smanip<streamsize> __cdecl setprecision(streamsize);
_MRTIMP2 _Smanip<streamsize> __cdecl setw(streamsize);
_STD_END
 #pragma pop_macro("new")
 #pragma warning(pop)
 #pragma pack(pop)
#endif /* RC_INVOKED */
#endif /* _IOMANIP_ */

/*
 * Copyright (c) by P.J. Plauger. All rights reserved.
 * Consult your license regarding permissions and restrictions.
V6.50:0009 */
```